# How to deal with unequal sample sizes while fully embrace a dataset?

Tags: r, logistic, sample-size

***Imagine the situation:*** Mythical Seafolk use holes in the seabed as their burrows. Each hole has two parameters - diameter and depth. **Majority of holes are unoccupied** due to their surplus (n = 235). Occupied holes (n = 15) are (generally) expected to be much deeper and with larger diameter than random.

```
# generate data
set.seed(1234)
x <- runif(250, min=0, max=10)
y <- runif(250, min=0, max=10)
rbPal   <- colorRampPalette(c("deepskyblue","darkblue"))
my.data <- data.frame(x_coor = x, y_coor = y,
                      diameter = c(abs(rnorm(15)+2.5), abs(rnorm(235))),
                      depth = c(abs(rnorm(15)+2.5), abs(rnorm(235))),
                      usage = rep(c(1,0), times = c(15, 235)))
my.data$col <- rbPal(10)[as.numeric(cut(my.data$depth,breaks = 10))]

# look at the situation
# occupied holes are marked by red circles
plot(my.data$x, my.data$y, cex = my.data$diameter, col = my.data$col, pch = 20)
grid(5, 5, lwd = 0.75, lty = 2, col = "grey") 
points(my.data$x[1:25], my.data$y[1:25], pch = 1, cex = 2,
       col = "red", lwd = 1.75)
```

[image]

Although this analysis seem to be rather straightforward, **I have some doubts about comparing unequal samples (15 vs 235)**. Such problem do not occur in other *Seafolk burrow selection studies* because **mapping of seabed is very expensive and time demanding** and when researchers find 10 used holes, they continue to map the seabed only till they get find additonal 10 nonused holes (which are most probably located in close vicinity of used holes). Due to this
data collection approach the sample sizes of compared groups are usually almost equal.
**However, we were able to find ALL holes in seabed - which can be now considered as a "handicap".**

***We do not want to do random sampling of 15 holes from 235 to obtain equal sizes (15 vs 15). Why to throw away such large amount of data!? Is there any solution/approach to this situation which is able to fully embrace such unique dataset?***

*I have in mind two possible ways (please comment or add others):*

**1.** Take the sample of unoccupied holes (n = 235) and randomly resample them to (for example 50) smaller groups (all with n = 15). Subsequently, each of these reduced groups will be compared with sample of occupied holes by binomial logistic regression. By this I will obtain 50 logistic curves which will
be "averaged" into just one curve - final model.

**2.** Take the sample of unoccupied holes (n = 235) and randomly resample them to (for example 50) smaller groups (all with n = 15). Subsequently, from each of these reduced groups (and from sample of used holes also) we gain (mean, sd, sample size). Thus, we will have six numbers for each comparison and we calculate effect size - standardized mean difference (SMD). Effect sizes will be inserted into meta-analytic model and tested if there is a heterogeneity present among effect sizes (*to see if the "randomnes" of creating unused holes sample has the significant impact on test result*).

Comment: Can you explain what the actual research question is? For example, whether diameter and depth differ between occupied and unoccupied holes? Or are you thinking more of diameter and depth being potential predictors for whether a hole is occupied or not?

Comment: Hi @Wolfgang. Second is true. I think of diameter and depth being potential predictors for whether a hole is occupied or not.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I see no reason for doing anything beyond just running a simple logistic regression model with the entire set of 250 data points.

Comment: Thank you @Wolfgang. And if I wanna know whether diameter and depth differ between occupied and unoccupied holes - the unequal sizes are problem in such case?

Comment: No, not really. You could run two t-tests then. The unequal sample sizes may be an issue if you run t-tests that assume that the true variances are the same when in fact they are not. Then the t-test may not be robust and could give you misleading results. But the solution then is not to chop up your data, but to just run t-tests that do not make that assumption (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_Unequal_sample_sizes.2C_unequal_variances). Or run non-parametric tests (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test).